# Setting up socket.io

Tags: node.js, proxy, websocket, socket.io

So I'm trying to run everything (serve web pages and run socket.io) over port 80.

> I have Apache2 listening on port 8000
>
> I have socket.io listening on port 8001

(Ubuntu 14.04)

Users connect to my site over port 80.

Here's my socket.io "server.js":

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8001);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Run with: `node server.js`

Here's my "proxy.js":

```
var httpProxy=require('http-proxy');
var proxy=httpProxy.createProxy();

var options = {
    'mysite.me': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'mysite.me/socket.io/': 'http://127.0.0.1:8001',
    'www.mysite.me': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'www.mysite.me/socket.io/': 'http://127.0.0.1:8001'
};

require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {  
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: options[req.headers.host],
        ws    : true
    });
}).listen(80);
```

Run with: `sudo node proxy.js`

My website is being served up fine through the proxy over port 80.

Socket.io is not working. It looks like it's trying to poll in Firebug.

Here's my index.html:

```
<script src="./lib/socket.io/socket.io-1.1.0.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('http://www.mysite.me:80');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
});
</script>
```

It works fine when I set:

`var socket = io.connect('http://www.mysite.me:8001');`

I've been at this for hours!